# Separating Names In Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a list of 60K names. I need to separate them into different worksheets based on their length.

I have been doing it using normal way using len() formula, filter them and copy paste them to separate sheet.

Is there any VBA code which I can use to do it ?

Example list

```
Name     Length
EMMALINE    8
EMMIE       5
EMMER       5
AMMIE       5
EMMY        4
AMMA        4
EMMELINE    8
EMMALEE     7
EMMALOU     7
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of that.

Comment: How are you filtering them?  More details would help to understand the task you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: using len() formula to find out the length of the word and use filter option and manually selection 4,5,6 etc from the dropdown menu

Answer (score 2):

This is just a sample approach.  First name the destination sheets as follows:

[image]

Then run this macro:

```
Sub croupier()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, s As String, M As Long

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        v = Cells(i, 1).Value
        s = "s" & Len(v)
        With Sheets(s)
            M = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(M, 1) = v
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```